# Check if Object Key and value contain certain words

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file with Question and Answer pair:

```
{
  "faq": {
    "How old is John?": "John is 30",
    "What color are Anna's eyes": "They are Blue",
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}
```

How can I filter the object for John, Anna and Jack?

Searching for John:

```
{
  "faq": {
    "How old is John?": "John is 30",
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}
```

Searching for Anna should return:

```
{
  "faq": {
    "What color are Anna's eyes": "They are Blue",
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}
```

Searching for Jack:

```
{
  "faq": {
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}
```

is there any way to search for single words in keys and value?

Comment: Bit strange that `faq` ins't an array.  Is that deliberate?  Using `.filter` would be most logical but will only work if it's an array

Comment: The question is about JavaScript objects, not about JSON. [JSON](https://json.org) is text, it does not have keys, values, indices, anything. JSON is a text representation of some data structure and it is very good to store or to transport the data. It cannot be used as is to search or to modify the data. When the JSON is retrieved from the storage or received at the destination, it needs to be parsed to restore data structures similar to those used to create them. The data structures (JavaScript objects in your case) can be searched, modified etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function .. it checks each pair in the object and if either the key or value matches, it'll get returned in a new object.

```
const search = (term) => {
    let results = {};
    for (item in data.faq) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || data.faq[item].toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) {
            results = {...results,[item]:data.faq[item]};
        }
    }
    return {faq: results};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if Object Key **and** value contain certain words

```js
const that = {
  "faq": {
    "How old is John?": "John is 30",
    "What color are Anna's eyes": "They are Blue",
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}

const filterKVcontains = (obj, str) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(
    e => e.every(
      it => (new RegExp(str, 'i')).test(it)
    )
  )
)
    
const filteredFAQ = filterKVcontains(that.faq, 'john')

const demo = document.createElement('pre')
demo.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({'faq':filteredFAQ}, null, 2)
document.body.appendChild(demo)
```

Let's focus on the variable `obj`, we give it to

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) that returns an array made from the properties of `obj`, where each element is itself an array with two entries, one for the key, the other for the value.

We pass this array of k/v entries to

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that returns only the elements of the array it operates on, that meet the criterion defined in the function it receives as parameter. We run it on the list of key/value pairs, with the following condition:

  - [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) that returns true if all elements of the array, now our key/value pair, satisfy the condition given as argument through a function:

    - [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) wich returns true if the string it is fed matches the regular expression it is run against. Our regular expression is built around `str`, the parameter to `filterKVcontains`
- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) Step out and rebuild the object from the filtered list of key/value entries

---

To check if Object key **or** value contain the words:
substitute [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which verifies whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your object is

```
const that = {
  "faq": {
    "How old is John?": "John is 30",
    "What color are Anna's eyes": "They are Blue",
    "What's the name of Anna and John child?": "His name is jack"
  }
}
```

You can filter keys containing "John"

```
Object.keys(that.faq).filter(e => e.indexOf("John") >= 0)
```

"Anna"

```
Object.keys(that.faq).filter(e => e.indexOf("Anna") >= 0)
```

et cetera

Comment: Would it work with Jack? that appears just in the value.

Comment: sorry missed that part. but you can apply the very same method then join the resultsets.